# Buttons not showing up in Firefox WebExtension notifications

Tags: javascript, firefox, notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a Firefox WebExtension in which I am trying to display a notification with a button. I have this working in Chrome. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/create), this is supported in Firefox. Buttons are listed as Optional in the [NotificationOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/NotificationOptions).

```
chrome.notifications.create(notificaitonId, {
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("images/unknown.svg"),
       title: "Blah",
       message: "A Message",
       buttons: [{title: "Get More Details"}]
});
```

When I run this code, I see the notification. But, I don't see a button.  Am I missing something? Is it actually not supported? The only [example for notifications](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n/background-script.js) doesn't use buttons so that hasn't been helpful.

Comment: In what version of Firefox are you testing? If not already, are you testing in [Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)? If not working there, have you tested in [Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/)? Firefox WebExtensions is a new API which is currently undergoing significant development. What is supported changes from one version of Firefox to the next. You may already be testing against those, but, at least to me, putting out effort to look into it (e.g. in the FF source code, or creating an extension to test) without verifying the above first isn't justified.

Comment: I am using the Developer Edition 47.0a2 (2016-03-16). I haven't tested in Nightly. I will do that next and provide an update.

Comment: I just tried this in Nightly with the same result.

Comment: Here I modified the notify link clicks example to show a button as well. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_ymjiwF4v35LXRDdVA4OWNXcjA&usp=sharing

Comment: @Makyen did you have a chance to verify yourself? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. We both missed something obvious. I will write a detailed answer now, but the gist is that buttons are not yet implemented.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the quick update. I'll await the more detailed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, buttons are not, as of 2016-03-18, implemented for WebExtension notifications.

The [NotificationOptions documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/NotificationOptions) states [emphasis/formatting mine]:

> The first four properties - `type`, `iconUrl`, `title`, `message` - are
>   mandatory in [notifications.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/create), and optional in
>   [notifications.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/update). **Firefox currently supports only these
>   four properties**.

and in the [Browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/NotificationOptions#Browser_compatibility):

> Firefox only supports: `type`, `iconUrl`, `title`, `message`.

The important parts of this ("Firefox currently supports only these four properties" and Firefox only supports: `type`, `iconUrl`, `title`, `message`.) were [added to the documentation on 2016-03-07](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/NotificationOptions$compare?locale=en-US&to=1027336&from=1027292). Thus, if you looked at the documentation prior to that date there would have been no indication that `buttons` was not yet implemented.

In addition, the [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/extensions/ext-notifications.js#108) has the comment:

> // FIXME: Lots of options still aren't supported, especially
>   // buttons.

You can also find the source code that is currently in use for this in your browser at: `chrome://extensions/content/ext-notifications.js`

#### Solution: Implement `buttons` yourself:

**In WebExtensions:**
It *might* be possible to implement buttons yourself from within WebExtensions. However, I am not familiar enough with WebExtensions to be able to say if it is possible, or not. If so, you will probably want to take a look at the [source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/notification.xml) that implements notifications and notification buttons for other types of Firefox add-ons.

**For Firefox, generally:**
If it was something I needed, I would probably choose to go ahead and implement `buttons`, and any other options I needed, for the entirety of Firefox and submit the code to Mozilla for review and inclusion in Firefox. I know this might sound like it is a big deal and a pain in the rear, but it really shouldn't be that difficult.

If you do desire to work on it, it should not take any special setup.  The JavaScript code which implements notifications for WebExtensions is the file *ext-notifications.js* which is contained in the *chrome\toolkit\content\extensions* directory within the *omni.ja* file (just a `.zip` file with the extension changed to `.ja`) which is located in the Firefox install directory. Note there are actually 3 different *omni.ja* files within the install directory hierarchy. The one you want is in the root of install hierarchy, not the ones in either the *browser* or *webapprt* sub-directories.

Working on it would be as simple as extracting that file, modifying it, making an updated *omni.ja* file and putting the updated *omni.ja* file into the release directory. For a while, I did this routinely upon every release of Firefox because I wanted a longer bookmark MRU file list. I eventually broke down and just made an overlay extension, [Change Bookmark Recent Folder List Length](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-/), to replace the file I was making changes to. If you want, you could do the same thing to implement the changes needed to support buttons. That would, of course, result in your current extension being dependent on the other one being installed until such time as the code was integrated into Firefox. But, it would result in both your having the functionality you desire now for your development, and the functionality getting into Firefox at least somewhat faster than waiting for someone else at Mozilla to implement it. An overlay extension like that just takes a [*install.rdf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests) file, a two line [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) file and the updated *ext-notifications.js* file you are wanting to override/replace over the current one.

Comment: Open issue on adding buttons support: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190681

Comment: Sadly, MDN is very vague on the issue. It says "Firefox only supports: type, iconUrl, title, message." but referenced to FF45 which would normally mean only FF45. It is unclear from the documentation that if that refers to FF45 only or not.

Comment: @erosman, I assume you mean the FF45 in the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/NotificationOptions#Browser_compatibility) section. If so, you are interpreting that section inaccurately. When a version is stated in any Browser comparability section on MDN then it means the first version in which the functionality existed/worked and it works in all later versions, unless very explicitly stated as meaning something else (e.g. a range of versions). The: "1. Only 'type', 'iconUrl', 'title', and 'message' are supported." (continued)

Comment: indicates only a subset of the functionality is supported. I agree the MDN page, if it was intended to only cover Firefox functionality, could be much more clear that only a limited subset is supported. Mozilla has chosen the WebExtension docs will be a confusing miss-mash of implementations. Specifically, that it will document the Promise (`browser.`) interface while describing things that are only available in the callback interface (`chrome.`), under non-Firefox platforms. I've argued for things to be less confusing, but I've not gotten agreement (except for a brief time in late 2016).

Comment: @Makyen ... yes .. at first, I read it as FF45 implemented only those options, which is correct. But then, a whole lot of other options are listed and no text to say that they are not supported. Therefore the assumption could be that FF45 started with those options but then the rest were added. It could have been made clearer :)

Comment: @erosman, Yeah, it could be clearer. However, it's consistent with how MDN generally states browser support. If there's a change in a later version (e.g. more things supported), there will be another version listed, probably with another note stating what limitations existed in that version and later. There could be multiple version entries with a note for each. This is generally consistent with similar listings in other such places, but there's no actual standard.

Comment: Part of the problem is that WebExtension docs are a transition from documenting other types of Firefox Add-ons, which are Firefox specific, to sort-of-kinda (the `browser.*`/`chrome.*` issue) documenting part of an already existing implementation (Chrome) in a way that is intended to be cross-browser compatible, yet maintain something of a Firefox focus. It does actually try to document what is/will be implemented across multiple browsers. However, what's really supported is a moving target, in all but Chrome, which doesn't support `browser.*` (yet everyone is striving for parity with Chrome).